# Vim substitution of fractional numbers

Tags: vim

I have a huge file with the following format i.e fractional numbers with sign.

1.00, 4.000,-1.8765,0
56.456, -7.10, -6.65, 3.340,
...
...

I would like to change this format by inserting these numbers into signed[number] into say.

signed[-1.00], signed[4.000], signed[-1.8765], signed[0]

How can i do it vim?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

this line would work for your example:

```
:%s/[0-9-.]\+/signed[&]/g
```

Comment: @powernest `[\d]` means `[d]` so , the letter `d`

Answer (score 0):

```
'<,'>s/[0-9][0-9.]*/signed[\0]/g
```

adjust the range for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
:%s/\v-?\d+(\.\d+)?/signed[&]/g
```

`\v` - turns on very magic mode.
`-?\d+(\.\d+)?` is look for any number. Negative sign and fractional part optional.
`&` - in the replacement part replaces it with the match.

```
1.00, 4.000,-1.8765,0 56.456, -7.10, -6.65, 3.340, ... ...
```

Turns into

```
signed[1.00], signed[4.000],signed[-1.8765],signed[0] signed[56.456], signed[-7.10], signed[-6.65], signed[3.340], ... ...
```